# Getting one loop for multiple characters using "while"

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm new on Stackoverflow and I'm very, completely new to coding. Just messing around with C. Here's what I'm trying to do here (don't take this program scientifically accurate), this is a program that calculates for special relativity equations of length, mass and time. I have 3 questions actually:

When I try to put other characters in the y/n questions, everything works but for example if I enter "sfkl", the warning comes up 4 times because I entered 4 characters. And if I put space, it doesn't even give a warning until I put another character and then enter. Can I make it give 1 warning no matter how many characters I enter in one line (including space)?

My other question is, I kind of prevented inputting anything other than y/n but for the double value inputs (mass, length and time), I can't figure out a similar system (asking for a double value over and over again). Can you suggest me a solution?

And my third question is, when doing "scanf_s(" %c", &answer);", if I don't put a space before "%c", it doesn't work properly. It registers an enter and asks me to enter y/n only. Why need a space before that?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define LIGHT 299792458

int input();

int main()
{
    printf("\n\n\tThis program calculates how length, mass and time changes with respect to your speed.\n\n\tThe values you enter are the quantites which are observed by a stationary observer and the output values are the quantites observed by the person in a vehicle which is moving at the speed that you enter.");

    input();

    return 0;
}

int input()
    {
        double length, mass, utime, speed;
        char answer;

        do
        {
            printf("\n\n     **************************************************");

            printf("\n\n\tPlease enter a quantity of length: ");
            scanf_s("%lf", &length);

            printf("\n\tPlease enter a quantity of mass: ");
            scanf_s("%lf", &mass);

            printf("\n\tPlease enter a quantity of time: ");
            scanf_s("%lf", &utime);

            printf("\n\tNow enter the speed of the vehicle (m/s): ");
            scanf_s("%lf", &speed);

            while (speed > LIGHT)
            {
                printf("\n\n\tNothing can surpass the speed of light in the universe. Enter a smaller value: ");
                scanf_s("%lf", &speed);
            }

            double newlength = length * (sqrt(1 - pow(speed, 2) / pow(LIGHT, 2)));
            double newmass = mass / (sqrt(1 - pow(speed, 2) / pow(LIGHT, 2)));
            double newutime = utime / (sqrt(1 - pow(speed, 2) / pow(LIGHT, 2)));

            if (speed == LIGHT)
            {               
                printf("\n\n     **************************************************");

                printf("\n\n\n\tIt's technically impossible to reach the speed of light if you have mass but here are the mathematical limit results:\n\n\t*The new length quantity is 0\n\n\t*The new mass quantity is infinity\n\n\t*The new time quantity is infinity\n\n\n\t- Time successfully dilated -\n\n");

                printf("\n\tDo you want to start over? (y/n): ");
                scanf_s(" %c", &answer);

                if (answer == 'n')
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (answer == 'y')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n')
                    {
                        printf("\n\tPlease only enter 'y' or 'n': ");
                        scanf_s(" %c", &answer);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (speed < LIGHT)
            {
                printf("\n\n     **************************************************");

                printf("\n\n\n\t*The new length quantity is %.20lf\n\n\t*The new mass quantity is %.20lf\n\n\t*The new time quantity is %.20lf\n\n\n\t- Time successfully dilated -\n\n", newlength, newmass, newutime);

                printf("\n\tDo you want to start over? (y/n): ");
                scanf_s(" %c", &answer);

                if (answer == 'n')
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (answer == 'y')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n')
                    {
                        printf("\n\tPlease only enter 'y' or 'n': ");
                        scanf_s(" %c", &answer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (answer == 'y');

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you, have a good day

Comment: Stop using `scanf()`. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `scanf` is the number of elements parsed successfully; you can use this to repeat until something has been read successfully:

```
double nr=0;
while (!feof(stdin) && scanf("%lf",&nr)!=1) {
  printf("not a number; try again.");
  while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }
}
```

Note that you have to take "invalid" input out of the buffer; otherwise, `scanf` would fail again and again.